# How to parse timestamp to JSON in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I wanna create a NodeJS application with an API which provides a current timestamp in JSON-format. This JSON should be called when the user calls the /api/current_time path.

The format could be look like this:

```
{  
"date" : 24,  
"month": 12, 
"year" : 2020,
"hours" : 10,
"minutes" : 10,
"seconds" : 54
}
```

I would work with Date-Object. How can I parse these variables into a new JSON-File? The values should be refreshing when the user presses F5.
How can I realize this?
Thanks.

Comment: Curious, what do you have so far?

Comment: _"parse these variables into a new JSON-File?"_ - What's a _"JSON-File"_ in this context?

Comment: I want to store these values as JSON. When I call the API I wanna get these values in JSON-Format. Sorry, im new into JSON and WebDevelopment. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to return a JSON when the `/api/current_time` path gets called. I suppose you mean JSON object instead of "JSON-File". If so, something as simple as:

```
const date = new Date();

const dateRepresentation = {
    year: date.getUTCFullYear(),
    month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
    day: date.getUTCDate(),
    hours: date.getUTCHours(),
    minutes: date.getUTCMinutes(),
    seconds: date.getUTCSeconds()
};

return JSON.stringify(dateRepresentation); // or simply - return dateRepresentation;
```

The returned date will be in UTC.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, will try out these solution later. :)

Comment: Nice, it works. I get the values in JSON-Format. Thanks. Is there a way to get the current timestamp, too? At the moment, I only get the timestamp from the moment NodeJS-Server was started.

Comment: @BraunStrowman Yes, of course. Try "date.getTime()". It will return a timestamp in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You Can also use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).

I am reusing zhulien example with moment :

```
const currentDate = moment(); //get the current Timestamp.

return dateObject = {
seconds = currentDate.format('ss'),
minutes = currentDate.format('mm'), 
hours = currentDate.format('hh'),
year = currentDate.format('YYYY'),
month = currentDate.format('MM'),
day = currentDate.format('DD')
};
```